# Can't authenticate youtube api client with access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube-api

My backend generates the `access_token` with below redirect controller:

```js
const logged = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const code = (req.query.code as string) || null;
  const state = (req.query.state as string) || null;
  const error = (req.query.error as string) || null;

  const oauth2Client = new youtube.auth.OAuth2(
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    GOOGLE_SECRET,
    GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
  );

  const { tokens: { access_token }} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
  res.send({ access_token });
};
```

Returned code is similar to: `"ya29.<MUCH_MORE_CHARACTERS_HERE>_BtA0163"`

Then somewhere else I'm trying to create a client with this access token like this:

```js
const youtube = require("@googleapis/youtube");
const youtubeApi = youtube.youtube({
  version: "v3",
  auth: "ya29.<MUCH_MORE_CHARACTERS_HERE>_BtA0163",
});
```

(Btw I'm aware that I could get the client on the redirect controller. I just don't want to)

But everytime I try to access something, it gives me error:

```json
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your expected goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use your access token to the client with googleapis for Node.js.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const youtube = require("@googleapis/youtube");
const youtubeApi = youtube.youtube({
  version: "v3",
  auth: "ya29.<MUCH_MORE_CHARACTERS_HERE>_BtA0163",
});
```

#### To:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2();
auth.setCredentials({ access_token: "ya29.<MUCH_MORE_CHARACTERS_HERE>_BtA0163" });
const youtubeApi = google.youtube({ version: "v3", auth });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So is there no way for setting the access token from the googleapis' submodules like youtube? I'm asking because they are much smaller.

Comment: @Alk Thank you for replying. About `So is there no way for setting the access token from the googleapis' submodules like youtube?`, when googleapis for Node.js is used, this method might be suitable. But, if you can achieve your goal without using googleapis, in this case, how about directly requesting the endpoint using `requests` module instead of googleapis for Node.js? By this, your access token can be directly used by including it in the request header. But, if this was not useful, I apologize.